# Emptying A Select Form Element With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dom

I am creating a small app and on one part of the app, i am creating a drop down select menu, that is populated with values from an array.

The problem i have is that when the form is loaded, it successfully loads and populates the select options with array values, but the problem is that when i add another element to an array and call the form again, it will still only load the values from when the form was first called.

How would i have the select option clear its values when i press the submit button. Here is the code the is called:

```
<div class="popupForm" id="newRelate_Form" style="display:none">
    <form name="relationFormOne">
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            var $selectFrom = $('<select id="mySelect">');
            $($selectFrom).attr('id', 'objFrom');
            for (var i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++)
            {
                var value = objectArray[i].Name;
                $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo($selectFrom);
            }
            $selectFrom.appendTo($("#from_Object"));
            var fromVal = document.getElementById("objFrom");
        </script>
        <button class="closeDOMWindow" onclick="createObj(fromVal.options[fromVal.selectedIndex].text)">Create</button>
    </form>
```

The value is then passed to the function createObj():

```
function createObj()
{
    /*
        DO THE WORK NEEDED
    */
}
```

Now what javascript code would clear the select option so that when it is called again it can be repopulated with any new objects placed into the array?

Thanks for any feedback.

BTW the popup form refers to the fact that im using the following jquery plugin: [DOM Window](http://swip.codylindley.com/DOMWindowDemo.html)

Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript:

```
var ob = document.getElementById('selectID');
while (ob.hasChildNodes())
    ob.removeChild(ob.firstChild);
```

jQuery:

```
$('#mySelect').children().remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to delete the previously created select tag using `$('#mySelect').remove()` and then run the function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the best way to add a piece of html is to write it from string:

```
<form id="relationFormOne">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(function(){
var objectArray = [{Name:'1'},{Name:'2'},{Name:'3'}];
var selectHtml = [];

$('#relationFormOne').append($('<select name="mySelect">'));

$(objectArray).each(function(ix, val){
    selectHtml.push('<option>'+val.Name+'</option>');
});
$('select[name=mySelect]').html(selectHtml.join(''));
}); 
</script>

<input type="button" value="clear" onclick="$('select[name=mySelect]>option').remove()" />
</form>
```

When you want to clear your select just use the code like the following:

```
$('#mySelect>option').remove();
```